# Any way to share code with others in IBM Quantum Lab?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

Is there any way to share code with others in IBM Quantum Lab, so they can view all updates without being logged into your account?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a support chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is currently no other way to share a notebook in the IBM Quantum Lab other than by importing it from your local machine.